# Error when parsing JSON array from http response from php/sql request : Unexpected token in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json, parsing

I'm trying to retrieve a JSON array from a mySQL Database with a php script. Here is the concerned php function :

```
function load_kid_table(){

    // Load datas and connect to database
    @$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    @$request = json_decode($postdata);
    require_once '../connect.php';
    @$mysqli = connect();

    @$user_id = $request->{'userId'};
    @$filter = $request->{'filter'};
    @$project_id = $filter->{'project_id'};

    // Do the request
    @$SQLrequest = "SELECT kid.*, kid.was_delivered AS 'kid_delivered', kid.fpy AS 'kid_fpy', product_line.product_line_description AS 'product_line_name', m.description AS 'milestone_description' FROM kid
    LEFT JOIN product_line ON product_line.product_line_id = kid.product_line_id
    LEFT JOIN milestone as m ON m.milestone_id = kid.milestone_id
    WHERE kid.project_id = $project_id;";

    //Add filters

    if (@$filter->{'kid_id'}) { // Filter on ID
        $SQLrequest .= " AND kid.kid_id = '".$filter->{'kid_id'}."'";
    }
    if (@$filter->{'description'}) { // Filter on description
        $SQLrequest .= " AND kid.description LIKE '%".$filter->{'description'}."%'";
    }
    if (@$filter->{'type'}) { // Filter on his type
        $SQLrequest .= " AND kid.type = '".$filter->{'type'}."'";
    }
    if (@$filter->{'product_line_name'}) { // Filter on description
        $SQLrequest .= " AND kid.product_line_name = '".$filter->{'product_line_name'}."'";
    }
    if (@$filter->{'milestone_description'}) { // Filter on his dependency
        $SQLrequest .= " AND m.description LIKE '%".$filter->{'milestone_description'}."%'";
    }
    if (@$filter->{'product_line_id'}) { // Filter on product line id
        $SQLrequest .= " AND kid.product_line_id = '".$filter->{'product_line_id'}."'";
    }
    if (@$filter->{'provider_id'}) { // Filter on provider
        $SQLrequest .= " AND kid.provider_id LIKE '%".$filter->{'provider_id'}."%'";
    }
    if (@$filter->{'provider_add_info'}) { // Filter on provider info
        $SQLrequest .= " AND kid.provider_add_info LIKE '%".$filter->{'provider_add_info'}."%'";
    }
    if (@$filter->{'requester_id'}) { // Filter on requester
        $SQLrequest .= " AND kid.requester_id LIKE '%".$filter->{'requester_id'}."%'";
    }
    if (@$filter->{'requester_add_info'}) { // Filter on requester info
        $SQLrequest .= " AND kid.requester_add_info LIKE '%".$filter->{'requester_add_info'}."%'";
    }
    if (@$filter->{'criticity'}) { 
        $SQLrequest .= " AND kid.criticity = '".$filter->{'criticity'}."'";
    }
    if (@$filter->{'maturity'}) {
        $SQLrequest .= " AND kid.maturity = '".$filter->{'maturity'}."'";
    }
    if (@$filter->{'fpy'}) { 
        $SQLrequest .= " AND kid.fpy = '".$filter->{'fpy'}."'";
    }
    if (@$filter->{'delivery_date'}) {
        $SQLrequest .= " AND kid.delivery_date = '".$filter->{'delivery_date'}."'";
    }
    if (@$filter->{'need_date'}) {
        $SQLrequest .= " AND kid.need_date = '".$filter->{'need_date'}."'";
    }
    if (@$filter->{'lower_need_date'}) {
        $SQLrequest .= " AND kid.need_date >= '".$filter->{'lower_need_date'}."'";
    }
    if (@$filter->{'upper_need_date'}) {
        $SQLrequest .= " AND kid.need_date <= '".$filter->{'upper_need_date'}."'";
    }
    if (@$filter->{'lower_delivery_date'}) {
        $SQLrequest .= " AND kid.delivery_date >= '".$filter->{'lowerdelivery_date'}."'";
    }
    if (@$filter->{'upper_delivery_date'}) {
        $SQLrequest .= " AND kid.delivery_date <= '".$filter->{'upper_delivery_date'}."'";
    }
    if (@$filter->{'lower_planned_date'}) {
        $SQLrequest .= " AND kid.planned_date >= '".$filter->{'lower_planned_date'}."'";
    }
    if (@$filter->{'upper_planned_date'}) {
        $SQLrequest .= " AND kid.planned_date <= '".$filter->{'upper_planned_date'}."'";
    }

    // Add order
    if (@$filter->{'order'}){
        $SQLrequest .= " ORDER BY ".$filter->{'order'}. " ASC";
    }       

    @$res=array();
    if (@$SQLresult = $mysqli->query($SQLrequest)) {
        while ($row = $SQLresult->fetch_assoc()) {
            $res[] = $row;
        }

        $SQLresult->free();
    }

    // Return results
    @$json=json_encode($res);
    echo($json);
    exit;

}
```

Here is the response of the http request, executed from a service in my Angular 5 application :

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ﻿ in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (webpack-internal:///../../../common/esm5/http.js:2289:51)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:421:31)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4967:33)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:420:36)
>       at Zone.runTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:188:47)
>       at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:496:34)
>       at invokeTask (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:1540:14)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:1566:17)

The text response below is the JSON array I'm looking for but after some researchs, I got a special character at the beginning of my string :

```
"﻿[{"kid_id":"1","description":"liste AD applicable + issue","type":"1","project_id":"120","milestone_id":"693","product_line_id":"2","provider_id":"zanneta","provider_add_info":"","requester_id":"vinays","requester_add_info":"","criticity":"2","maturity":"3","fpy":"","need_date":"2018-08-15","planned_date":"2018-08-15","was_delivered":"N","delivery_date":null,"modified":"0","input_modified":"0","creation_date":null,"modification_date":"2018-09-19 17:04:04","kid_delivered":"N","kid_fpy":"","product_line_name":"Other","milestone_description":null},{"kid_id":"2","description":"Contrat client","type":"1","project_id":"120","milestone_id":"693","product_line_id":"2","provider_id":"castac","provider_add_info":null,"requester_id":"castac","requester_add_info":null,"criticity":"2","maturity":"3","fpy":"Y","need_date":"2018-09-01","planned_date":"2018-09-01","was_delivered":"Y","delivery_date":null,"modified":"0","input_modified":"0","creation_date":null,"modification_date":null,"kid_delivered":"Y","kid_fpy":"Y","product_line_name":"Other","milestone_description":null},{"kid_id":"3","description":"Position orbital","type":"2","project_id":"120","milestone_id":"693","product_line_id":"2","provider_id":"castac","provider_add_info":null,"requester_id":"","requester_add_info":null,"criticity":"1","maturity":"2","fpy":"Y","need_date":"2018-09-03","planned_date":"2018-09-03","was_delivered":"Y","delivery_date":null,"modified":"0","input_modified":"0","creation_date":null,"modification_date":null,"kid_delivered":"Y","kid_fpy":"Y","product_line_name":"Other","milestone_description":null},{"kid_id":"4","description":"Analyse de risque system (RAO)","type":"1","project_id":"120","milestone_id":"693","product_line_id":"2","provider_id":"castac","provider_add_info":"","requester_id":"castac","requester_add_info":"","criticity":"2","maturity":"3","fpy":"Y","need_date":null,"planned_date":"2018-09-04","was_delivered":"","delivery_date":null,"modified":"0","input_modified":"0","creation_date":null,"modification_date":"2018-09-20 10:22:40","kid_delivered":"","kid_fpy":"Y","product_line_name":"Other","milestone_description":null},{"kid_id":"5","description":"Liste lanceur applicables et des d?rogs","type":"1","project_id":"120","milestone_id":"694","product_line_id":"3","provider_id":"castac","provider_add_info":"","requester_id":"durieze","requester_add_info":"","criticity":"3","maturity":"1","fpy":"N","need_date":"2018-09-05","planned_date":"2018-09-05","was_delivered":"","delivery_date":null,"modified":"1","input_modified":"0","creation_date":null,"modification_date":"2018-09-19 17:04:42","kid_delivered":"","kid_fpy":"N","product_line_name":"Altimetry","milestone_description":null},{"kid_id":"6","description":"Life time + EOR duration","type":"1","project_id":"120","milestone_id":"693","product_line_id":"2","provider_id":"vinays","provider_add_info":"AIT","requester_id":"zanneta","requester_add_info":"DTF","criticity":"2","maturity":"3","fpy":"Y","need_date":"2018-08-06","planned_date":"2018-08-11","was_delivered":"Y","delivery_date":null,"modified":"0","input_modified":"0","creation_date":null,"modification_date":"2018-08-23 12:25:10","kid_delivered":"Y","kid_fpy":"Y","product_line_name":"Other","milestone_description":null},{"kid_id":"7","description":"Cas de chargement Payload Op?rationnels","type":"1","project_id":"120","milestone_id":"0","product_line_id":"0","provider_id":"-1","provider_add_info":"","requester_id":"-1","requester_add_info":"","criticity":"2","maturity":"3","fpy":"","need_date":"2018-09-08","planned_date":"2018-09-07","was_delivered":"N","delivery_date":null,"modified":"0","input_modified":"0","creation_date":null,"modification_date":"2018-09-12 11:15:37","kid_delivered":"N","kid_fpy":"","product_line_name":null,"milestone_description":null},{"kid_id":"8","description":"Conf plateforme EOR et G\/O","type":"1","project_id":"120","milestone_id":"693","product_line_id":"2","provider_id":"castac","provider_add_info":null,"requester_id":"zanneta","requester_add_info":null,"criticity":"2","maturity":"1","fpy":"","need_date":"2018-09-08","planned_date":"2018-09-08","was_delivered":"Y","delivery_date":null,"modified":"0","input_modified":"0","creation_date":null,"modification_date":"2018-08-17 17:07:21","kid_delivered":"Y","kid_fpy":"","product_line_name":"Other","milestone_description":null},{"kid_id":"9","description":"Product SOA Solar Array","type":"1","project_id":"120","milestone_id":"696","product_line_id":"2","provider_id":"zanneta","provider_add_info":null,"requester_id":"castac","requester_add_info":null,"criticity":"2","maturity":"2","fpy":null,"need_date":"2018-09-09","planned_date":"2018-09-09","was_delivered":"","delivery_date":null,"modified":"0","input_modified":"0","creation_date":null,"modification_date":null,"kid_delivered":"","kid_fpy":null,"product_line_name":"Other","milestone_description":"Delayed milestone"},{"kid_id":"10","description":"Product SOA SADM G3","type":"1","project_id":"120","milestone_id":"696","product_line_id":"2","provider_id":"castac","provider_add_info":"","requester_id":"zanneta","requester_add_info":"","criticity":"1","maturity":"3","fpy":"","need_date":"2018-09-01","planned_date":"2018-09-01","was_delivered":"N","delivery_date":null,"modified":"0","input_modified":"0","creation_date":null,"modification_date":"2018-08-28 09:35:10","kid_delivered":"N","kid_fpy":"","product_line_name":"Other","milestone_description":"Delayed milestone"},{"kid_id":"11","description":"Product SOA ADPMX+e\/HRM2x","type":"1","project_id":"120","milestone_id":"50","product_line_id":"0","provider_id":"vinays","provider_add_info":"","requester_id":"-1","requester_add_info":"","criticity":"3","maturity":"2","fpy":"","need_date":"2018-09-12","planned_date":"2018-09-12","was_delivered":"N","delivery_date":null,"modified":"0","input_modified":"0","creation_date":null,"modification_date":"2018-09-12 11:15:39","kid_delivered":"N","kid_fpy":"","product_line_name":null,"milestone_description":"Constituants : STB EGSE EMH V2"},{"kid_id":"12","description":"D?finition des sc?narios d?ouverture\/fermeture \ndes ex","type":"1","project_id":"120","milestone_id":"693","product_line_id":"1","provider_id":"zanneta","provider_add_info":null,"requester_id":"vinays","requester_add_info":null,"criticity":"3","maturity":"1","fpy":"Y","need_date":"2018-09-12","planned_date":"2018-09-12","was_delivered":"","delivery_date":null,"modified":"0","input_modified":"0","creation_date":null,"modification_date":null,"kid_delivered":"","kid_fpy":"Y","product_line_name":" ","milestone_description":null},{"kid_id":"24","description":"","type":"0","project_id":"120","milestone_id":"693","product_line_id":"1","provider_id":"","provider_add_info":null,"requester_id":"","requester_add_info":null,"criticity":"0","maturity":"0","fpy":"","need_date":null,"planned_date":null,"was_delivered":"","delivery_date":null,"modified":"0","input_modified":"0","creation_date":null,"modification_date":null,"kid_delivered":"","kid_fpy":"","product_line_name":" ","milestone_description":null},{"kid_id":"32","description":"","type":null,"project_id":"120","milestone_id":"1","product_line_id":null,"provider_id":"TBD","provider_add_info":null,"requester_id":"TBD","requester_add_info":null,"criticity":null,"maturity":null,"fpy":null,"need_date":null,"planned_date":null,"was_delivered":null,"delivery_date":null,"modified":"0","input_modified":"0","creation_date":"2018-09-14 10:26:58","modification_date":"2018-09-14 10:26:58","kid_delivered":null,"kid_fpy":null,"product_line_name":null,"milestone_description":"ADR"},{"kid_id":"33","description":"","type":null,"project_id":"120","milestone_id":"1","product_line_id":null,"provider_id":"TBD","provider_add_info":null,"requester_id":"TBD","requester_add_info":null,"criticity":null,"maturity":null,"fpy":null,"need_date":null,"planned_date":null,"was_delivered":null,"delivery_date":null,"modified":"0","input_modified":"0","creation_date":"2018-09-17 14:30:48","modification_date":"2018-09-17 14:30:48","kid_delivered":null,"kid_fpy":null,"product_line_name":null,"milestone_description":"ADR"},{"kid_id":"34","description":"","type":null,"project_id":"120","milestone_id":"1","product_line_id":null,"provider_id":"TBD","provider_add_info":null,"requester_id":"TBD","requester_add_info":null,"criticity":null,"maturity":null,"fpy":null,"need_date":null,"planned_date":null,"was_delivered":null,"delivery_date":null,"modified":"0","input_modified":"0","creation_date":"2018-09-17 17:26:38","modification_date":"2018-09-17 17:26:38","kid_delivered":null,"kid_fpy":null,"product_line_name":null,"milestone_description":"ADR"},{"kid_id":"35","description":"","type":null,"project_id":"120","milestone_id":"1","product_line_id":null,"provider_id":"TBD","provider_add_info":null,"requester_id":"TBD","requester_add_info":null,"criticity":null,"maturity":null,"fpy":null,"need_date":null,"planned_date":null,"was_delivered":null,"delivery_date":null,"modified":"0","input_modified":"0","creation_date":"2018-09-19 18:36:15","modification_date":"2018-09-19 18:36:15","kid_delivered":null,"kid_fpy":null,"product_line_name":null,"milestone_description":"ADR"}]"
```

When checking the network request, I can see that a "red point" corresponds to the invalid character. It seems like it's an \ufeff character.

In parallel, all the others requests from my other scripts php are working well.

Can you help me to figure out where does this error comes from ?

Thanks by advance !

Comment: Welcome. Can you `var_dump` the content of `$res` before calling `json_encode` on it? On another note, using `@` everywhere is really bad practice and your SQL queries seem prone to SQL injection attacks. Look into [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Somebody should take away your `@` key. Ignoring errors does not make them go away!

Comment: And a quick look at [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in `MYSQLI_` would also help you greatly

Comment: Will all those `@`s this code is the equivalent of sticking your fingers in your ears, closing your eyes, and shouting 'LALALALALA' while running through traffic.